# Objective C: How to recognise unicode characters that display the 'Alien' or '?' symbol on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, utf-8, nscharacterset

I'm currently working on a project involving filling the address book of an iPhone. One requirement of this task is that the address book is filled with random UTF-8 characters.
However, some of these appear as an 'alien-head' or '?' (Sorry I need 10 rep to post a picture of them T_T).

Has anyone either found a way to recognise which characters cause this, or know of a CharacterSet of iPhone displayable unicode characters?

Thanks

Comment: Now u can post a picture of them. So you do it urgently